getting the status of an stm32 device in dfu mode
i have written a simple code to get the status of a connected stm32 device in dfu mode. I can get the information on the device but always gets error when checking the status from the get_status method.
Below is my code.
import usb
import time
import usb.backend.libusb1


# DFU Commands
DFU_DETACH = 0x00
DFU_DNLOAD = 0x01
DFU_UPLOAD = 0x02
DFU_GETSTATUS = 0x03
DFU_CLRSTATUS = 0x04
DFU_GETSTATE = 0x05
DFU_ABORT = 0x06

class STDFU:
    def __init__(self):
        # Initialize the device (replace with your device's VendorID and ProductID)
        self.device = usb.core.find(idVendor=0x0483, idProduct=0xDF11, backend=usb.backend.libusb1.get_backend(find_library=lambda x: "libusb-1.0.dll"))

    if self.device is None:
        raise ValueError("Device not found.")

    # Set up the device (claim interface, reset device, etc.)
    self.device.set_configuration()
    self.device.reset()
    time.sleep(2)  # Ensure the device has time to reset

def get_device_info(self):
    
    if self.device:
        print(f"Device: {self.device}")
        print(f"Device Configuration: {self.device.get_active_configuration()}")
        # Removed the line that tried to access the 'state' attribute
        print("Device state info is not available via pyusb.")
    else:
        print("No device found.")

def get_status(self):
    
    try:
        if self.device is None:
            raise ValueError("Device not initialized.")

        print("Sending DFU_GETSTATUS request to device...")
        response = self.device.ctrl_transfer(0xA1, DFU_GETSTATUS, 0, 0, 6, timeout=20000)
        print(f"Received response: {response}")

        # Assuming response follows this format:
        dfu_status = DFUStatus()
        dfu_status.status = response[0]
        dfu_status.poll_timeout = response[1] | (response[2] << 8) | (response[3] << 16)
        dfu_status.state = response[4]
        dfu_status.iString = response[5]

        print(f"DFU Status: {dfu_status}")
        return dfu_status

    except usb.core.USBError as e:
        print(f"Failed to get status: {e}")
        raise



stdfu = STDFU()
stdfu.get_device_info()  
dfu_status = stdfu.get_status()

I always run into this error:
usb.core.USBError: [Errno None] b'libusb0-dll:err [control_msg] sending control message failed, win error: A device attached to the system is not functioning.\r\n\n'.
I could get the device info though. This is a snippet of it.
evice: DEVICE ID 0483:df11 on Bus 000 Address 255 =================
 bLength                :   0x12 (18 bytes)
 bDescriptorType        :    0x1 Device
 bcdUSB                 :  0x100 USB 1.0
 bDeviceClass           :    0x0 Specified at interface
 bDeviceSubClass        :    0x0
 bDeviceProtocol        :    0x0
 bMaxPacketSize0        :   0x40 (64 bytes)
 idVendor               : 0x0483
 idProduct              : 0xdf11
 bcdDevice              : 0x2200 Device 34.0
 iManufacturer          :    0x1 STMicroelectronics
 iProduct               :    0x2 STM32  BOOTLOADER
 iSerialNumber          :    0x3 366337783238
 bNumConfigurations     :    0x1
  CONFIGURATION 1: 100 mA ==================================
   bLength              :    0x9 (9 bytes)
   bDescriptorType      :    0x2 Configuration
   wTotalLength         :   0x36 (54 bytes)
   bNumInterfaces       :    0x1
   bConfigurationValue  :    0x1
   iConfiguration       :    0x0 
   bmAttributes         :   0xc0 Self Powered
   bMaxPower            :   0x32 (100 mA)

A help will be really appreciated. Thanks in adavance.

Your code works for me (after removing all things related to the missing DFUStatus class). I'm assuming you are on Windows too and have installed the WinUSB driver for your device. So possibly you are using a different pyusb/libusb version, your STM32 chip has a defect (in the built-in bootloader) or the USB hardware part of your device only works partially.

You could also try this Python DFU software: https://github.com/manuelbl/usbx/tree/main/examples/stm32dfu. It does not use pyusb/libusb but a more modern USB implementation. So it might indicate if the problem is related to pyusb/libusb.

@Codo Thanks a lot for the suggestion. I will check the link you provided and let you know if it works. I really appreciate your help

@Codo. I was able to finally get details from my dfu device. However, I run into another issue when traying to claim it for exclusive usage. Error while claiming interface 0: claiming interface failed - The data area passed to a system call is too small.

I have found the issue. I have to install the WinUSB driver since am using windows. Its working as expected now
